# Calculate shipping taxes for a custom woocommerce cart API endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I have been trying to build a custom Woocommerce Cart API endpoint, I implemented the add to cart feature but **I have ended up facing an issue with shipping taxes**.

I want to calculate shipping taxes (especially for flexible_shipping_single) but my code isn't working :

```
 $shippings = [];
        if (isset($request["shipping_lines"]) && !empty($request["shipping_lines"])) {
            foreach ($request["shipping_lines"] as $shipping_line) {
                $shippings[] = $shipping_line["method_id"];
            }
            WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', $shippings);
        }
 $cart->calculate_totals();
```

Here's my request (I removed some lines to minimize the size)

```
{
 "line_items": [
        {
            "product_id": 15071,
            "variation_id": 0,
            "quantity": 9
        }
    ],
"shipping": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "postcode": "94103",
        "country": "US"
    },
"shipping_lines": [
        {
            "method_id": "flexible_shipping_single",
            "method_title": "Flexible Shipping"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The issue:

The issue was in the param `"state": CA` that doesn't exist in the state's list of the shipping zones, So the `calculate_shipping()` couldn't find the shipping package related to the shipping method selected by the user and its rates, which means that the **flexible_shipping_single** won't work, instead, it sets back the default shipping method, in my case **wc_pickup_store**